# How to create Delete function in My Order page

Tags: magento2.3, delete, action

I want to add a new action in **My Orders** page that is Delete action
[image]

How can I do that? Can anyone help me with this function?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a following files

**Create this file at Path app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/sales_order_history.xml**

> sales_order_history.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sales.order.history">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::order/history.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> history.phtml

Copy this file from Path
**vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/order/history.phtml**

to your module

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/order/history.phtml**

> Add this code to after line no. 43, instead of this code `$block->getViewUrl($_order)` you can write your logic to delete order.

```
<a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getViewUrl($_order) ?>" class="action delete">
    <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Delete') ?></span>
</a>
```

> here is whole code of history.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php $_orders = $block->getOrders(); ?>
<?= $block->getChildHtml('info') ?>
<?php if ($_orders && count($_orders)): ?>
    <div class="table-wrapper orders-history">
        <table class="data table table-order-items history" id="my-orders-table">
            <caption class="table-caption"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Orders') ?></caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" class="col id"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Order #') ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="col date"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Date') ?></th>
                    <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getChildHtml('extra.column.header') ?>
                    <th scope="col" class="col shipping"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Ship To') ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="col total"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Order Total') ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="col status"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Status') ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="col actions"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Action') ?></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($_orders as $_order): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Order #')) ?>" class="col id"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_order->getRealOrderId() ?></td>
                        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Date')) ?>" class="col date"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->formatDate($_order->getCreatedAt()) ?></td>
                        <?php $extra = $block->getChildBlock('extra.container'); ?>
                        <?php if ($extra): ?>
                            <?php $extra->setOrder($_order); ?>
                            <?= /* @noEscape */ $extra->getChildHtml() ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Ship To')) ?>" class="col shipping"><?= $_order->getShippingAddress() ? $block->escapeHtml($_order->getShippingAddress()->getName()) : '&nbsp;' ?></td>
                        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Order Total')) ?>" class="col total"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_order->formatPrice($_order->getGrandTotal()) ?></td>
                        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Status')) ?>" class="col status"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_order->getStatusLabel() ?></td>
                        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Actions')) ?>" class="col actions">
                            <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getViewUrl($_order) ?>" class="action view">
                                <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('View Order') ?></span>
                            </a>
                            <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getViewUrl($_order) ?>" class="action delete">
                                <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Delete') ?></span>
                            </a>
                            <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Sales\Helper\Reorder')->canReorder($_order->getEntityId())) : ?>
                                <a href="#" data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo
                                $this->helper(\Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper::class)
                                    ->getPostData($block->getReorderUrl($_order))
                                ?>' class="action order">
                                    <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Reorder') ?></span>
                                </a>
                            <?php endif ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <?php if ($block->getPagerHtml()): ?>
        <div class="order-products-toolbar toolbar bottom"><?= $block->getPagerHtml() ?></div>
    <?php endif ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="message info empty"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('You have placed no orders.') ?></span></div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your kindly answer my question. It's the first time I create a new function in Magento 2, can you spend a little time to tell me about this function? How can I delete my orders

Comment: ok let me make the changes

Comment: Yes, I will wait for your answer while I am researching

Comment: ok. I'm still working on it. Made some changes to delete order but need to pass it as url on delete action.

Comment: did you find solution to delete order ?

Comment: Oh no, I had research but I cannot find it